# Static content with Viewpager in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've tried multiple ways of adding a footer and a header in activity_main.xml which has a viewpager inside it. So far when I add a header above the viewpager, it's shown in final result but the footer isn't. 
Here is the xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg50"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextColor="#FFF" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new LoginFragment(), "Login");
    adapter.addFragment(new RegisterFragment(), "Register");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

[sreenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FeXh.jpg)
So the question is ,how to display content below the view pager.

Comment: Your question is unclear well at least to me . Can you edit it, what exactly the problem is .

Comment: any content below the viewpager is not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a static footer below `ViewPager` you can use layout below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:background=""
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextColor="#FFF" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your viewpager layout height to wrap_content.

Or just change your root layout to `<RelativeLayout>` and set add this tag to your view pager.

Like so:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    ...
    <ViewPager
      ...
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@id/your_footer_id"/>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wrap_content doesn't work. But if I set a fixed height -say 300dp- it works. How to make it work with wrap_content ?

Comment: Simple and direct!

Answer (score 0):

Set to your viewpager:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This will make it fill all available space in LinearLayout after other children are laid out.